# Magento 2 - How I can upload svg image from backend custom module's add/edit page?

Tags: magento-2.1, svg

I want to upload svg image using uploader from backend but it throws the error:

> disallowed extension

I have also change xml file `<your magento dir>/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml` as:

```
<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="svg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
    <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Did you found the solution